# How do I exclude a dependency in provided scope when running in Maven test scope?

Tags: java, maven, maven-2

How do I exclude a dependency in provided scope when running in Maven test scope? I have an unusual use case where I need to exclude a particular provided implementation and replace it with another in the test cases. It seems that Maven tests always include other scopes as well but in my case I want to make some exception. How do I do this?

Comment: Sounds weird. Do you have a little bit more details?

Comment: I'm trying to build test cases but I can't find old ebeddable servlet containers in any repositories I know. The framework I'm using only allows newer servlet container which is included in our dependencies as "test". The old servlet version is included in our dependencies as "provided". Mixing those in the classpath is, of course, causing exceptions. Hence, the need for excluding the old servlet from the classpath in the Maven test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are situations where you need to run your tests in a different module.  That may be what you need here. It allows your tests to use different dependencies, properties and version of Java etc.

Comment: I guess there's really no other way. I believe this is the cleanest approach I could find.

Answer (score 2):

I think, the simplest way to do this is to create 2 profiles for each dependency you want to use. You can activateByDefault the one with provided scope.

It may look like this :

```xml
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>providedDependency</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>[provided dependency information]</dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>testDependency</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>[test dependency information]</dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

When passing into test mode, unactivate the provided dependency and activate the other

```
mvn test -P!providedDependency,testDependency
```

Comment: Profile based seems don't integrate well with m2e eclipse plugin. Eclipse's JUnit plugin doesn't integrate too. Is there a way to switch between profiles in eclipse and have eclipse switch the libraries according to what's defiined in the profile? I can't debug through the codes without this. Couldn't find any better solution than this so far. Maybe I should try separating it in a different module and see if that works.

Comment: Have you tried, in Eclipse, to create a "Run Configuration --> Maven B uild" with goals "test" and profiles "!providedDependency,testDependency". You can then debug your jUnit test.