# Automatically replacing one Maven plugin with another in a POM

Tags: maven, replace, pom.xml

Please do you know if it's possible to automatically replace one Maven plugin with another in the POM files for a project?

The context is that I'm trying to intercept a Scala build using a Scala compiler plugin, for which I want to be able to specify the Scala compiler plugin as an argument to `scalac` from the command-line (i.e. not within the POM files). This is possible using the latest version of the Scala Maven plugin (known as scala-maven-plugin) by using its `addScalacArgs` flag - see here: http://davidb.github.com/scala-maven-plugin/apidocs/scala_maven/ScalaMojoSupport.html. However, it's not possible for the old version of the plugin (known as maven-scala-plugin), and I'd need to add the argument in all the various POM files (not an attractive proposition when dealing with a large, third-party project).

My thinking is that if I can automatically replace the old version of the plugin with the new version in the POM files, then I can use `addScalacArgs` and everything will work out well. I can probably cook up some code to do this (evidently doing it manually would be no better than going through and adding the argument), but it seems like the sort of thing that might be a supported Maven use-case.

Being specific, I'm trying to replace this plugin:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.scala-tools</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-scala-plugin</artifactId>
  ...
</plugin>
```

with this one:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
  <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  ...
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with two profiles in your pom. One activate by default the other not. Then you can easily select which to use accordingly which profile you choose.

For exemple, here is a older post in the same spirit : [How do I exclude a dependency in provided scope when running in Maven test scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12314397/how-do-i-exclude-a-dependency-in-provided-scope-when-running-in-maven-test-scope/12314578#12314578)

Comment: I'm not sure I completely follow unfortunately - please could you explain further? The trouble I've got is that it isn't my POM at all - it's a set of third-party ones in a large build. I'm trying to come up with a way of getting things to work that is as minimally-invasive as possible.

Comment: Ok, I see. I thought plugin definition was in your pom. Unfortunalty, in this case, i don't see any solution. I'll think about it

Comment: Thanks for the help in any case. For what it's worth, I eventually found another solution - I built my own custom version of maven-scala-plugin 2.15.2 that does support `addScalacArgs` and installed it into the local Maven repository in place of the real one. Problem solved :)

Comment: Good solution too :) Maybe try to put these modification to plugin repository, it can be useful to integrate it in future version